# How to make a regex which will match any file ending with .rtf?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.6

So I was doing a project in which I had to write a program that opens all .rtf files in a folder and searches for any line that matches a user-supplied regular expression and the results had to be printed to the screen.

The code was quite easy but I am having a hard time to write a regex that will match any file ending with `.rtf`.

Here is  a **string** of all the files inside a folder in which Python will search for the files ending with `.rtf`:

`rxn of glucose.png Screen Shot 2017-07-17 at 8.25.30 AM.png Screen Shot 2017-08-18 at 11.23.21 AM.png Screen Shot 2017-08-18 at 11.36.27 AM.png Screen Shot 2017-08-19 at 6.06.19 AM.png SSS.rtf Untitled 2.rtf Untitled 3.rtf Untitled 4.rtf Untitled.rtf`.

I tried many regexes like:

1) `(\w+\.rtf)`

Take a look at it's result:https://regex101.com/r/oZzN6T/1

2)`[a-zA-Z0-9].rtf`

https://regex101.com/r/RaeL0Z/1

3) `.+\.rtf`

https://regex101.com/r/8hRIGo/1

The desired results are : `Untitled 2.rtf Untitled 3.rtf Untitled 4.rtf Untitled.rtf SSS.rtf` but the some of the regexes above are matching some part of these files and others are matching the entire text itself!

None of these regexes work properly. I do understand that why they are not working but I am not able to fix them. How should I modify them or otherwise what should be the new regex that would match the files with extension `.rtf` in the given string?

Comment: @JonUleis it's matching the entire text just like one of my regexes

Comment: Why on earth do you have that in a **string**???

Comment: @jordanm because I have not studied it yet. Also, don't you think that `str.endswith('.rtf')` will match the entire string?

Comment: How exactly should it match files like `Untitled 4.rst`? It seems like one whitespace is the seperator between files as well as a valid character in filenames. That's going to be really difficult. If there could be more than one `.` in a filename it would say it's impossible.

Comment: @StefanPochmann even if I have those in `lists` or something I am going to face the same problem

Comment: @M.Hamel Nonsense. It would then be trivial (`endswith('.rtf')`). Instead of impossible.

Comment: Is it possible this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? If you want to match all files with a specific ending just use [`glob.glob('*.rst')`](https://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#glob.glob)?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I got it! Thanks! That solved the problem. :-) But it would be nice if I could get a regex for this as it looks like a good problem to me

Comment: @M.Hamel You mean a regex for that large combined string or for individual filename strings?

Comment: @StefanPochmann for the individual filename strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to mention that this seemed like a job for python, but here's what I came up with to answer your question using just regex:

`((?<=\.\w{3} )|^)[\w ]+\.rtf`

This successfully finds all files with the extension ".rtf", even at the beginning of the string, by starting to look either after the end of the most recent file name or at the beginning of the string. This does assume, however, that all of the file extensions are 3 characters long. If you might have file extensions of length 2 (for example, `*.7z`) or something else, you should add `(?<=\.\w{2} )|` (or whatever the other file lengths are) after the first open parenthesis. This would give you:

`((?<=\.\w{2} )|(?<=\.\w{3} )|^)[\w ]+\.rtf`

Answer (score 0):

matches all printable characters case insensitive which end in .rtf

```
/^[ -~]\.rtf$/i
```

Comment: In *nix, non-printable characters are valid for filenames. The only two things not valid is `\0` and `/`.